# How do I make a loop to read/download file from server (in client-server application)?

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop, client-server, bufferedreader

In my client-server application, the client sends `GET filename` command to the server in order to download the file. Now the client must be able to read the buffer size (of file residing in server) and download it into the client. That's I have done inside a while loop. My concern is about that loop in client class:
Is the looping correct? The way I am reading the file ...?

I think I should specify the filesize inside the loop. Then how it could be done or improved?

This is the portion of code I am working on.

ClientSide:

```
 if (request.startsWith("GET")) {
                    File file = new File(request.substring(4));
                        is = socket.getInputStream();
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[socket.getReceiveBufferSize()];
                        int bytesReceived = 0;
                        while ((bytesReceived = is.read(buffer)) >=0) {
                            //while ((bytesReceived = is.read(buffer))>=buffer) {
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
                        }
                        request = "";
                        fos.close();
                        is.close();


     }
```

ServerSide:

```
  try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                            os = socket.getOutputStream();
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[(1 << 7) - 1];
                            int bytesRead = 0;

                            while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }

                        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is an implementation of HTTP protocol, the client might not not the size of the file, which is being send by the server. One approach is the server always sends "Content-Length" header and client reads up to this length.More info HTTP specification: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
The other approach is client reads until the connection is closed by the server. When server sends the whole file, it closes the connection. This is not very reliable, as connection might be dropped due to network problem.

Comment: Anton K., yes HTTP protocol

Comment: Anton K., but is my looping correct in client side?

Comment: It is correct, in case the server closes connection after it sends the file.